# SQL Server 2012 Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

Please help me out with a problem I am facing.

I have a table `T`. I altered the table to alter the column `C` from `varchar(10)` to `varchar(100)`.

Now, there is a view `V` that is schema bound and selects columns from `T`. So before altering `T`, I had to drop the view `V`.

Steps I followed:

1. Drop view V;
2. Alter T alter C varchar(100);
3. (re)create V.

Error I am facing:

> Replication-Replication Distribution Subsystem: agent XXX failed. The
>   object 'V' is dependent on column 'C'. I performed the changes in
>   Preprod environment. Table T is in replication.

I want to know:

1. How to fix this error
2. what did I do wrong?

Comment: You'll probably do better asking on [dba.se]

Comment: I managed to fix this issue. 

Reason: the error occurred because of the schema bound view V on the subscriber DB as well. The schema bound view was not letting SQL Server replicate the changes made to T.C

My learning: Column changes (datatypes) along with a whole bunch of other schema changes made  on publisher db get automatically replicated onto the subscriber DBs (refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).

Fix: I just dropped view V on the subscriber DB for a few minutes to let replication make the DDL changes in the subscriber DB and recreated it afterwards.

Comment: Posting it here as Stack overflow won't let me answer my own question :)